# Getting average values per day in MongoDB using Moongose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to get some data from mongoDB and I'm using moongose. The elements (Documents) in the collection are simple like this:

```
{"created_at":"2018-05-16T15:58:24.979Z","_id":"5afc5520b237951510da6a0c","value":15.5,"__v":0}
```

I need to get the Average of the "values" per each day starting from today, in the previous week, eg:

> today: Monday

I want an array like this [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] where:

Last Monday Average = 1

Last Tuesday Average = 2

....

Today Average = 8

Is there a way to do it directly in mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do an aggregation that includes theses steps:

1. Break down the `created_at` field to get the day of month, month and year separately,
2. Get the average of `value` of each day.

This is the code:

```
YourCollection.aggregate([
{
   $project:
     {
       year: { $year: "$created_at" },
       month: { $month: "$created_at" },
       day: { $dayOfMonth: "$created_at" },
       _id: "$id",
       value: "$value"
     }
},
{
   $group:
     {
       year: "$year",
       month: "$month",
           day: "$day",
           avgValue: { $avg: "$value" } 
         }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I've done it this way:

    MyCollection.aggregate()
      .group({
        _id: {
          year: { $year: "$date" },
          month: { $month: "$date" },
          day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
          week: { $week: "$date" },
          weekDay: { $dayOfWeek: "$date" },
        },
        avg: { $avg: "$temp" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      })
      .sort('-_id')
      .limit(8)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you . You did it better than I did